# Getting error TypeError: recordaccess.success is not a function from below code

Tags: angularjs, json

I am using the code specified below and getting an error. Please help me. Let me know if I can write it in better way:

```
RecordApp.factory('recordaccess', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('record.json').then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            return response.data;
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("Error occurred. Status: " + response.status + " - " +  response.statusText);
       }
    );
}]);

RecordApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'recordaccess', 
    function($scope, recordaccess) {
        recordaccess.success(function(data) {
            $scope.record1 = data;
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: The code portion was shown as text. I improved the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a plunker that has the factory and the controller that you have and seems like changing `recordaccess.success` to `recordaccess.then` fixes the problem:

Seems like that's because `success` is only available on `$http` and when it returns, a `$q` promise is returned. Which doesn't have `success`

https://plnkr.co/edit/53fDfhjwcVXJNMD4KsoQ?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much .. It worked . I am very new to angularjs and your quick an accurate answer helped me here .